# Accessing runtime functions from Red/System

Tags: red, red-system

So the issue came up while experimenting with marshaling values back and forth between Red and Red/System.  I would like to access the guts of an object passed to a routine.

I had noticed that there are functions in the Red Runtime for handling things like this, get-values, get-words, etc in the object context.  There is a file in the runtime sources called [`object.reds`](https://github.com/red/red/blob/7ff7458999b90d5f38952939fd9f95c5cdbb759e/runtime/datatypes/object.reds)

How do I utilize these?  Can I utilize these?  Is there a way to access them without re-including (and by extension compiling) a copy of the (already included) runtime into my app?

Comment: Please add a short code example to illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call these from inside Red/System routines right away. No additional include is necessary. Here's a brief example:

```
Red []

get-object-size: routine [
    obj [object!]
    return: [integer!]
] [
    object/get-size obj
]

print get-object-size object [foo: 42 bar: 99]
```

When you compile and run this, it will eventually output `2`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for each Red datatype there is a Red/System file in the sources (see the [repository](https://github.com/red/red/tree/master/runtime/datatypes)) which defines a `context` whose name is the same as that datatype without the `!` (except for `context!` and `function!`, where a `_` is prefixed to avoid name clashes). Within such a `context`, there are functions defined for each of the `actions` on values of that type, as well as auxiliary functions that may be useful within routines. However, I would imagine that the auxiliary functions, not being tied to the language specification, are not guaranteed to be there as the implementation evolves. Thus I would caution against relying on them too much.